# Customisations with apex

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata-api, metadata

I have two objects: Object A and Object B.

I want to push picklist values of Object A to Object B picklist values using metadata api.How can I achieve this using code?

Comment: do you want to create pick-list options using metadata API?

Comment: Yes Ex:Object A:Status Picklist value :A,b,c,d should move to Object B:Status value:which is empty

Comment: I will be writing batch next how do i do using metadata api

Comment: check this tutorial https://sfdcweb.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/add-list-of-values-in-custom-object-picklist-field-options-using-metadata-api/